# getting error while connecting to database with shell script

Tags: mysql

i have a simple shell script that is trying to connect to a database and is trying to load a text file into a database table through load infile statement inside a script and the script throws this error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 6: Access denied for user 'user'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

The script is

```
#!/bin/bash

#connect to the db
mysql -u bsm_admin -pbsmP1N1 -h ilcldbpbsm01 << EOFMYSQL
show databases;
use database;
show tables;
load data infile 'plugins.txt' into table jenkins fields terminated by ':' lines terminated by '\n';
EOFMYSQL
```

so the problem is other statememts work but the error comes at load data infile line.

i tried checking whether the user has write permissions to the database and i was able to create and insert data to the table through command line, so i am guessing it is not a permission issue.
Also i didnot create the user, it was already created.

Comment: grand user permission on `%` in MySQL server

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE without the "LOCAL" keyword tries to locate the specified file in the MySQL data directory on the server where MySQL runs. The file must be there (/var/lib/mysql on Ubuntu) and must be readable by the user who runs MySQL. The error message is likely because of file permission issues.

Comment: @marekful i tried that too..same error

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have `FILE` privilege. Refer to [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file)

`The FILE privilege gives you permission to read and write files on the server host using the LOAD DATA INFILE and SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statements and the LOAD_FILE() function.`

Comment: i am able to run the same command from command line in the db and it works fine...it is just that it does not work inside my shell script..any idea why?i am guessing it is not a permission issue

Comment: that's weird, then probably check if any typo about username, password, etc.